# Selenium, is_displayed() function is throwing an error when run

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have an element on my webpage that was deleted and now I need to check that the deletion has actually successfully deleted the element, I have the following code

```
element = driver.findElements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pr_id_1-table"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]/a[2]')

if element.is_displayed():
    print("Test failed: Element is visible.")
else:
    print("Test passed: Element is not visible.")

driver.quit()
```

I'm getting the following error when run,

```
 if element.is_displayed():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_displayed'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `element = driver.findElements(By.....` after this line add this `print(element)`. if it prints None. Then check why is the element none.

Comment: The `find_elements` returns `List[WebElement]`, you should instead use `for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ...):`

Comment: I don't think there is a method `findElements` in python selenium drivers, try using [find_elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=find_elements#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements) instead